# How to detect if web script in Perl is run using ModPerl::Registry (mod_perl handler)?

Tags: perl, web-applications, mod-perl

Is it possible in to detect in web app run under mod_perl if it is run using [ModPerl::Registry](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/Registry.html)?

I want to write script which would run under ModPerl::Registry (or similar handler), but can function also as mod_perl response handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModPerl::Registry does an elaborate dance to isolate your code from everything else in the system, and part of that is compiling it into a package beneath `ModPerl::ROOT`.

When called in list context with an argument specifying the number of frames to go back, [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) returns

> ```
> #  0         1          2      3            4
> ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
> #  5          6          7            8       9         10
> $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
>  = caller($i);
> ```

where the `$subroutine` value is a fully-qualified name.

ModPerl::Registry wraps your entire program in a sub named `handler` in the aforementioned artificial package, so from your main program, use a test similar to

```
my $name = (caller 0)[3];
if ($name =~ /^ModPerl::ROOT::/) {
  # run using ModPerl::Registry
  ...
}
```